# How I can access the ActiveRecord Job after enqueuing a job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job, rails-activejob

I want to access my ActiveRecord job item after enqueueing a task

```
job = MyCustomJob.perform_later
```

`Job` is a `MyCustomJob`, but how I can access it without doing something like `Delayed::Job.last`?

Answer (score 2):

`job.provider_job_id` is the `Delayed::Job`'s `id` so you could do `Delayed::Job.find(job.provider_job_id)`.

Code is here: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activejob/lib/active_job/queue_adapters/delayed_job_adapter.rb#L20